# Get list from object, modify and set in one line

Tags: java, collections

I need to get `List<Example>` from the object, add an element to it, and attach the modified list to the object. Is there a wise way to do it **in one line**? Right now it looks like the following:

```
List<Example> examples = user.getExamples();
examples.add(example);
user.setExamples(examples);
```

I thought about smth like this:

```
user.setExamples(user.getExamples().add(example));
```

but it does not work due to that
`add` returns `true`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with what you already have. Why do you want to do it in one line?

Comment: `Collection#add` is mutation method, that's why it returns result of mutation, not `this`. There is no elegant one-liner, if yout need you may write your own helper method.

Comment: Can you show us the `user` class?  The correct answer to this depends on whether `getExamples` returns a reference to the original list, or whether it makes a copy.

Comment: You would be probably able to create a addExample method in your User class that would suit all your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [object-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), you should think in terms of asking an object to "do its thing" rather than you trying to manipulate its innards from outside.

So rather than extract, manipulate, and re-inject, simply ask that object to add an item. You don't even know if there *is* a list inside that object. Let the object take care of tracking items as it sees fit.

```
user.addExample( myExample ) ;
```

In other words, having getters and setters is often a sign of poor object-oriented design.

If you insist on external modifications:

- If you know for certain the list returned by the getter is (a) the same list maintained within the object (generally a poor design) and is (b) modifiable, then you can use the approach seen in the [Answer by Patil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72207286/642706) where you call [`List#add`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#add(E)) on the object returned by the getter. I would add an `if` test to verify you got back `true`, as a `false` means the addition failed.
- If you want to pass the modified list to a setter method, then as you have seen, you cannot do so in a single line because the method return boolean. For a [fluent-style syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface), you would need an addition method that returned a reference to the list itself.

To use the setter, you must make multiple statements.

```
List< Example > list = user.getExamples() ;
if( list.add( myExample ) ) 
{
    user.setExamples( list ) ;
} else 
{
    … handle failure …
}
```

If that returned list is not modifiable, you'll need to make a new one. Pass the unmodifiable list to the constructor.

```
List< Example > list = new ArrayList<>( user.getExamples() ) ;
if( list.add( myExample ) ) 
{
    user.setExamples( list ) ;
} else 
{
    … handle failure …
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use it in one line, then this is one of approach which might suits your requirement.:

```
 user.getExamples().add(example);
```

Comment: That would add element to list returned by `getExamples()` which is probably *copy* of list held by `user` (otherwise `user.setExamples(examples);` wouldn't make sense).

Comment: @Pshemo more likely this is for some JPA staff that's why it is okay )

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to join a Collection (or specifically a List) with a single element and have the concatenated Collection returned in one line, you could do the following:

```
Stream.concat([Collection].stream(), Stream.of([element to add])).toList()
```

Or in your specific case:

```
user.setExamples(Stream.concat(user.getExamples().stream(), Stream.of(example)).toList());
```

Note that this makes use of the `.toList()` method on `Stream` introduced in Java 16. For earlier versions you can use `.collect(Collectors.toList())`.

This may not be the cleanest approach (it's certainly more verbose than a simple `.add()` on a Collection), but it can be nice for situations where you want to declare the concatenated collection in one line, rather than initializing it in one (with perhaps a misleading variable name), and adding to it in another.

Hope this helps!